# Codeigniter on Vestacp with Nginx return blank pages

Tags: php, codeigniter, nginx

I've setup my CI app on Vestacp (Ubuntu 14.04 vps server) with Nginx front. Most of the app seem to work just fine. But, many pages with or without database query result return blank.

Following test record is from apache error log

```
".. [16/Jul/2015:12:01:37 +0000] "GET /admin/test HTTP/1.0" 500 394 .."
```

And following test record is from Nginx access log

```
".. [16/Jul/2015:12:01:37 +0000] GET /admin/test HTTP/1.1 "500" 0  .."
```

There is not much details available on the access log.

And of course things are just fine on my development machine.

Answer (score 0):

All of public cms use ".htaccess" file to rewrite urls, if youre using nginx as main provider you need to convert all rewrites to nginx config